# Get value for a field from url while saving a new node

Tags: entities, nodes

How to find a next Entity ID/Node ID?

Here is my scenario. I created my own Content Type which has 10 fields, one of these 10 fields has to save to DB thru a custom module. Value to this field is being passed thru URL filter.

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: why and where you need next node id?

Comment: Why - To save an extra field into DB.

Comment: DO you mean you have added fields later to content type and there are nodes already created that needs to be updated?

Comment: Where - to use it in drupal_write_record() as entity_id. Not to add later but when node published/saved as draft this filed need to saved into DB

Comment: I am not sure if it helps you might be I am not able to get your question but here goes my answer you do not have to provide next node id system will give it by its own and it is in incremental order.

Comment: Yeah right. In my module I am using hook_form_alter, in form submit function I am trying to find next node ID and use it in drupal_write_record.

Comment: why not you using node_save()

Comment: If I use node_save() does it save other fields enter thru UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the comments so far , I could understand that you have a content type with 10 fields, so the time so create a node you will be putting 9 fields on the node form and the 10th field has to be filled with some value from url parameter,so lets assume your site url while adding the node looks like `www.sitename.com/node/add/your_content_type?field_value=xyz`.

One of the possible way can be to pick the value from url and make it as 10th field default value, an example code can go something like below.

```
 // Assuming 10th field as textfield.
 function mymodulename_hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
   if($form_id == "your_node_add_form_id") {
     if (is_null($form['nid']['#value'])) {
         $form['your_10th_field_machine_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['vaue'][#default_value] = $_GET['field_value'];
     }
   }
 }
```

Rest saving of fields will be handled by drupal itself.

Comment: Awesome this worked.Thank you arpitr. Everything working fine, only one thing is when I try to edit the node which was created with right values, this field is not populated. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Monu good point, check the updated answer